# Construct NSString from the description method of each NSArray item?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsarray

I have an `NSArray`, where each object contains a specific class called Card. Card has a description method. I want to join all objects in the array using the output of the description method, separated by spaces. Is there a simple to do this, without manually iterating the `NSArray` and manipulating `NSString`?

Something akin to the following made-up code?

```
NSArray *myArray = getCards(); // fetches 10 items or more
NSString *myString = [myArray joinUsingDescriptionMethodSeparatedBy:@" "];
```

or

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringFromArrayDescriptionMethods:myArray separatedBy:@" "];
```

Naturally ,I could implement this myself but I suspect there could be something already present that does this.

Comment: side note: you may want to change your method name, `-[NSObject description]` exists.

Comment: Indeed - it is the existing description method I want to use!

Comment: haha - i had the impression from "Card has a description method." that you had hidden the existing debugger-print-string method. nevermind! :)

Comment: The description method should not be used for anything outside of debugging.

Comment: @bbum can you point me to some docs that state this? Apple's NSObject reference says "A string that describes the contents of the receiver." It doesn't state that it shouldn't to be used outside of debugging.

Comment: The docs should be fixed (I filed <rdar://problem/12209310>).  Consider; you type `po someObject`.  You want that to be useful for debugging purposes.   But you are using `description` for UI and, thus, the result is (a) localized and (b) doesn't actually describe the object's contents, but it's user facing value.  Thus, you now have a `description` method that doesn't do what it is supposed to [describe the contents of the object].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that there is such a method. You can also implement it in a Category for NSString.

Sorry, I found this:

```
NSString * result = [[array valueForKey:@"description"] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
```

From the documentation:

> Constructs and returns an NSString object that is the result of
>   interposing a given separator between the elements of the array.

```
- (NSString *)componentsJoinedByString:(NSString *)separator
```

Comment: componentsJoinedByString is exactly what I wanted...I didn't realise it automatically used the output of the description method.

Comment: `description` in obj-c is the equivalent of `toString` in many languages. it's the method that will get called whenever you try to print or log an object

Answer (score 0):

Do this for description method of each NSArray item:

```
NSMutableString * result = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
for (NSObject * obj in array)
{
  [result appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@"[obj description]]];
}
NSLog(@"The concatenated string is %@", result);
```

Comment: This approach is what I want to avoid - it is such a common task that I thought there must already exist an API method to do what I wanted.